# Show welcome website before using wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot, advertisements, captive-portal

My idea is simple but i dont know how to do the result.

I made a free wifi hotspot in our "company" via tplink WR940N. 
All id like to do now, is to user, that uses our wifi, will be after he connects to our wifi, be redirected on our "example webpage" to show news. And after 30 seconds the internet will be allowed. Our city has also this kind of feature on public city and it is not bad idea.

Not sure if you really understand me.

Comment: The term you want to search for is "captive portal".

Comment: The word you are looking for is [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)

Comment: Wou guys. Unexpected fast reaction and ofc, the correct answer. All what i was needed. Thank you very much. ! Now i hope i can somehow set it up. Thanks you !

Comment: In case you solved this, it would be really nice if you could share what you did to set it up. You're encouraged to post it as actual answer, it's fine to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a "captive portal".

Here are some options of how to implement it:

Open Source/Free

- ChilliSpot
- Wifidog
- PacketFence
- HotSpotPA
- CoovaChilli
- Untangle captive portal
- pfSense
- PepperSpot
- Zeroshell

Closed Source/Paid:

- FirstSpot
- antamedia
- polkaspots

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, as well some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: I would have provided links to each of these, but I don't have enough reputation to post links.